# Writing parquet files from kinesis

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, parquet, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I need to save raw events from my server into a parquet file so I can query the data.
Is there an easy way to write parquet to s3 directly from kinesis using scala/java ?

Ideally I would like to use kinesis firehose to do the heavy lifting.

any idea ?